# Data modelling for eCommerce website in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I am building an e-commerce website for my client. I'm using MongoDB for storing data. But I'm pretty new to the concept of nosql.

In the site there will be couple of categories and under them products will came. Now I can't figure out how should I model my data.

Should I make a huge products collection and store product related documents in it and fetch them using tags?

Or should I make many small collection of categories and store similar category products in it?

Please, share how should I model products data and how can I get them efficiently.
And please Suggest your opinion if my approach is wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: store everything in one collection , create indexes on fields , and access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a single schema and implement *embedded data modeling* in your schema. So keep the most common features in the outer-most layer, then add small fragments of specialized data clusters. For example: 
[image]

Also please read the following articles to get more info:

[1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/)
[2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_data_modeling.htm)

Hope this helps.